# What are the shortcut keys for menus and choosing items?

Tags: moomoo.io

In moomoo.io, clicking on shop menu or team menu makes me lose a lot of time. Sometimes, in the middle of a fight I should change my characters hat because of its effects on my character. In addition to this time lose, you can't make any move if you open these menus. So I should reduce the inactive times.

Is there any shortcut keys for these menus? Is there any shortcut keys for choosing hats quickly?

Also wondering is there any shortcut to choose an item which the game offer you when you level up?